# triac switch with two power suppllies

Tags: triac

I'm building a furnace controller that should hook up in parallel to a home thermostat. The schematic of a thermostat-controlled furnace (omitting non-essential components) is below (Fig.1):
[image: Fig.1]

I would like to replace the switch (external thermostat unit) with a triac. The triac (T2) is controlled by a digital circuit (X1), which gets power from a wall-wart adapter (Fig.2):
[image: Fig.2]

If a user plugs in the wall-wart unit other way around, i.e. L and N on TR4 would be swapped - what would happen? I presume short-circuit. How can I avoid it? Except using optotriacs and polarized plugs?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue 9f the AC end of the wall wart is backwards as there's no such thing as backwards in an AC circuit, as an added honus the output of the wart will be isolated from the mains anyway. If you're really concerned, why not use a relay instead pf a triac? The relay's possibly a bit easier to interface to, unless you want to do PWM or something.

Comment: I conducted a field experiment, and the circuit didn't like it. There  is a potential difference between the common wire in the control circuit and in the switch circuit. And when the common wires are connected together with a 1k resistor - there is actually current flowing through it. For now the boards are already made so I will use a polarized plug on the wall-wart, but later -yes, relays would be the choice.

Comment: Did you mean the end that goes in the wall or the part that runs the circuit? L (Live) and N (Neutral - which will be tied to ground somewhere at the fuse box) are usually reserved for the (more deadly) mains side of things, the output of the wart going to the circuit is going to be + and - (unless it's an AC output, in which case there should be no difference - the input and output sides of a wart should be isolated internally, I'd be worried if they wern't)